# What component is this? Is it a capacitor or an inductor? Logic does not help

Tags: capacitor, inductor, components, surface-mount

[image]

Could you please tell me what kind of component this is?

Is it a color coded capacitor? Is it an inductor?

If I assume it is a capacitor it has color code 22pF +10% but the schematic does not help. It is placed at the positive input of an external DC 10V supply, so it should have no sense. The 0V DC and the +10V DC are connected in the differential input of an opamp, and with the capacitor in series current can't flow.

If it is an inductor of 47uH it is in another place it shorts Vcc to ground, so I assume it could be a capacitor, but as above it makes no sense.

Comment: where is the schematic?

Comment: Both resistors. 22R on the right (red-red-black-gold) and 4k7 on the left (yellow-purple-black-brown).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are resistors in a MELF package.

Comment: Also known as "Most End-up Lying on the Floor"